# Pretashop get new order details in a custom module

Tags: module, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am creating a custom module in Prestashop. In that module I want to get
the order details when a new order has been made on the store. So I want
to know which hook should I use and how to get new order details along with
customer details when a new order has been made. Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable.

Answer (score 3):

Use a hook `actionValidateOrder`. Hook gives you params array which includes `Order`, `Cart`, `Customer`, `Currency` and `OrderState` objects associated with it.

With them you can now get customer and order details.

```
public function hookActionValidateOrder($params) {
    $order = $params['order'];
    $customer = $params['customer'];

    $order_details = $order->getOrderDetailList();
}
```

Hook needs to be registered in module install.

```
public function install() {
    return parent::install && $this->registerHook('actionValidateOrder');
}
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. Can you tell me should I make it register hook when module is install? Is there any reference for this hook?

Comment: Yes you need to register hook in the module install. Sadly the hooks are not documented but if you have a good IDE (ie. PHPStorm) you can do a search in project for `Hook::exec` and it will show all the hooks in Prestashop.

Answer (score 1):

You can use displayOrderConfirmation hook in your main controller to get details of any order.

Following code can help you:

```
 public function hookDisplayOrderConfirmation($params = null)
{       
    $id_customer = $params['objOrder']->id_customer;
            //Get all other details using the $params['objOrder'] order object
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. Can you tell which hook should I install in the module to use this?

Comment: You need to install hook displayOrderConfirmation. 
$this->registerHook('displayOrderConfirmation')